# Codeigniter nivoslider images and css background images not showing?

Tags: css, codeigniter

I am writing a webpage with CI. I am a newbie. I cant manage to show my imagefiles on the page .
My directory structure is

```
+application
+system
+assets
  +css
  +js
  +images
```

I use nivoslider in a part and here is the div part :

```
<div id="slider-nivo">
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/nivoslider1.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/nivoslider2.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/nivoslider3.jpg" alt="" />
```

and also in css there is a part texturing the menu , I cant make the background picture work:

```
 #sidebar #sidebar-content #menu  li {background-image: url('../images/menu_li.png');
```

How can I show the pictures in the view and the css backgrounds?

Comment: You want to use CSS backgrounds instead of images?

Comment: no , I have nivoslider which I cant see pictures. and also background picture in my css which is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/images/nivoslider3.jpg" alt="" />
```

Maybe, your `base_url` is not `http://example.com/` but `http://example.com` and you get `http://example.comassets/images/nivoslider1.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

I found it . It is a permission error. I have given rights to read/write to others now it works now.

Comment: I use arch linux ... I changed permissions to 777 .

Answer (score 0):

@Vukašin
Usually you don't need foreslash after echoing *base_url()* function.

I had problems with implementing nivoslider to codeigniter and had seen it's something not well recommended on codeigniter forums. I take decision to implement jquery cycle all plugin. It finished all job for me.